# Filter category page products on Sidebar

Tags: attributes, category, product-attribute, filter, products

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around how I go about allowing my products to be filtered by custom attributes I have set for products. For example, I have a products called Computer 1. It's worth £100.00 and has a 1.2 processor with 1GB of Ram. I also have in the same category another computer called Computer 2, worth £150.00, 1.4 processor and 2GB. How could I list the varying attributes in the sidebar so people can narrow down a huge range of products by individual attributes? For example, if you view the following link:

```
http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/laptops-netbooks/laptops/laptops/703_7006_70006_xx_xx/xx-criteria.html
```

You can see that they allow for people to filter their products by Price, Manufacturer, etc. How would I go about doing that with my products and their attributes. Any help would be really appreciated. I've seen a few tutorials but they seem to want to play with the Mage Controllers, and as I understand it, I'm meant to leave those files of my website alone.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has built in filtering for attributes which you can easily setup from the admin.  Magento refers to this as **Layered Navigation**.

To make an attribute appear in the Layered Navigation for a category, there are few things you must do first.

1. Go to **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes**
2. Select the attribute you wish to make appear in the Layered Navigation
3. Set the option labeled **Use In Layered Navigation** to `Filterable (with results)`.
4. Click **Save Attribute**
5. Flush all of your Magento caches under **System > Cache Management**

Now if the attribute is assigned to any product within a category you are viewing, it should now appear as a filterable option in the Layered Navigation block.

If it does not appear, make sure it is assigned to at least one or two products within the category you are viewing.  In a mult-store setup, the attribute would only appear to the store it's assigned to be used in.

Comment: This doesn't seemed to have done anything i'm afraid, it's definitely assigned to the right store too.

Comment: What is the name of the filtered navigation block, for example, how would it be called in the CMS page for me to make sure it's included properly?